# How does the Julia Do Syntax for functions work?

Tags: function, syntax, julia

I've seen [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments) that `do` syntax can be used as a more convenient way to write `map()` functions, but I don't understand how e.g. in the example shown in the linked julia docs :

```
open("outfile", "w") do io
    write(io, data)
end
```

Which works on the following function definition of 'open'

```
function open(f::Function, args...)
    io = open(args...)
    try
        f(io)
    finally
        close(io)
    end
end
```

How in the world does the `do` pass the `io` and `write(io,data)` to the actual function of `open` and `f(io)`? Does the function with the `do` block have to have the same name/be multi-dispatched for the `do` block to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a purely syntactical transformation.

```
func(x) do y
    body
end
```

is equivalent to

```
func(y -> body, x)
```

or

```
tmp = y -> body
func(tmp, x)
```

if you will, i.e. the `do` block defines an anonymous function that is passed as the first argument. For this to work it is, of course, required that there exist a method of `func` that has a matching signature, for example `func(f::Function, ...) = ...` (or simply`func(f, ...) = ...`).

---

You can inspect what is really happening by using `Meta.@lower`:

```
julia> Meta.@lower func(x) do y
           print(y)
       end
:($(Expr(:thunk, CodeInfo(
    @ none within `top-level scope'
1 ─      $(Expr(:thunk, CodeInfo(
    @ none within `top-level scope'
1 ─      global var"#1#2"
│        const var"#1#2"
│   %3 = Core._structtype(Main, Symbol("#1#2"), Core.svec(), Core.svec(), false, 0)
│        var"#1#2" = %3
│        Core._setsuper!(var"#1#2", Core.Function)
│        Core._typebody!(var"#1#2", Core.svec())
└──      return nothing
)))
│   %2 = Core.svec(var"#1#2", Core.Any)
│   %3 = Core.svec()
│   %4 = Core.svec(%2, %3, $(QuoteNode(:(#= REPL[1]:2 =#))))
│        $(Expr(:method, false, :(%4), CodeInfo(
    @ REPL[1]:2 within `none'
1 ─ %1 = print(y)
└──      return %1
)))
│        #1 = %new(var"#1#2")
│   %7 = #1
│   %8 = func(%7, x)
└──      return %8
))))
```

The output is, unfortunately, garbled with implementation details of anonymous functions: The code defines a new struct (`%3`), makes it callable (`%4`) using the body of the `do` block, creates an instance of it (`%7`), and in the end calls `func(%7, x)`.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about the Meta.@lower function, that does seem pretty useful (though i will need to get better at understanding the lower level julia output).

Answer (score 4):

If it helps anybody, I have also discovered through fiddling what @fredrikekre has written generally, via this example:

```
function func(blah::Function,baz,foo)
   blah([baz,foo])
End
```

and you can call it as either of the following

```
func("a", "b") do zzz
   vcat(uppercase.(zzz),"C")
end

func(zzz->vcat(uppercase.(zzz),"C"),"a", "b")
```

both produce the same output

```
3-element Vector{String}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
```